How to translate the letter Q to Japanese?
I just started learning hiragana and I was wondering how to translate my name "Quinten" to hiragana. There is no Q used in hiragana so the most similar character I was thinking of is く(ku). This was my best try to translate my name as the following:
romanji: Ku u i n te n
hiragana: くういんてん
I'm not sure if this is correct. So I was wondering how we can translate the letter Q to Japanese?

When trying to convert a foreign word to hiragana, it's better if you don't focus on individual letters but on the actual sounds of the word.
You probably want to transliterate "Qui" as くい instead of くうい, as the "u" in "Quinten" isn't long enough to be granted an extra う, and く already includes the sound "u". If you add う between く and い it reads "ku u in ten", but I think "ku in ten" is closer to the original pronunciation.
Also, although you specifically asked for the transliteration to hiragana, note that foreign names and words from other languages are usually written in katakana, not hiragana:
くいんてん → クインテン
Finally, for the sake of completeness:

How to translate the letter Q to Japanese?

The letter Q is read キュー{kyuu} (or きゅう in hiragana), even though this is very different from the actual sound of Q inside the name "Quinten".

I went to Wikipedia for "Quentin Tarantino" and switched to Japanese to see "クエンティン" but of course, that's not exactly "Quinten."

@WGroleau If you see the edit history of my post, you will see I also inadvertedly typed Quentin instead of Quinten probably due to my subconscious mind recalling the great filmmaker as well.

Right, but I'm showing a way to get other languages’ versions of names.  I guess I should have said that explicitly.
